# Disable all elastic 5 hard limits and safegaurds

Tags: elasticsearch

According to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11511 elasticsearch 5 has some new limits, I know this is recommended for many use cases but How to disable all new limits for special use cases?

Comment: It looks like the list of limits is in the github issue you reference. Maybe you can clarify what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if these limit settings can be disabled all-together. You will rather need to alter (increase or decrease) them individually in case the default value for a particular limit doesn't satisfy your use case.

Comment: OK! Is there a reference to show us, how to disable each one?